# how to make main() function in sha512 in mbedtls

Tags: c, embedded

My purpose is to test sha512 and sha256 in eclipse tricore and here is the link for the sha512 code :https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/master/library/sha512.c

Following are the files required for the specified sha512 code.My problem is that I am not able to understand which files to include and which to not so that it can run.
https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/tree/master

Comment: Do you want your test to run on the mcu or on a desktop? If you would like to run on an mcu why not start an mbed project?

Comment: On the desktop. Later we'll test it on a simulator.

Comment: I see that tls has it's own desktop unit tests. Do these tests not cover yours?

Comment: Yes, they don't cover.

Comment: Can you build the existing tests? If so you could consider adding your tests to the existing framework

Comment: Thank you for your info. Adding the tests to the framework helped. Now its up and running.